# Python: is there a way to check "is stop requested" before each line in thread?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I want to be able to interrupt many threads at once. One solution could be:

```
stop_all_threads = False

def abort_if_requested():
    global stop_all_threads

    if stop_all_threads:
        raise Exception()


def thread_target():
    abort_if_requested()
    do_some_work()
    abort_if_requested()
    do_more_work()
    abort_if_requested()
    last_work_piece()


my_thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_target)
my_thread.start()

...

stop_all_threads = True
```

But obviously it's a bit annoying to follow and doesn't stop them immediately if the work functions take long. Is there a simpler way? I know about `multiprocessing.Process.terminate` but I have to use `threading.Thread` in my use case, or some other method that provides shared memory with low latency.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you're asking here but this is the only thing I can think of:

```
stop_all_threads = False

def abort_if_requested():
    global stop_all_threads
    
    if stop_all_threads:
        raise Exception()

def thread_target():
    def check():
        while True:
            abort_if_requested()
            time.sleep(0.75)
    checkThread = threading.Thread(target=check)
    checkThread.start()
    do_some_work()
```

Try to recode this because I don't really understand what you needed here.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the [`Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event) class from `threading` library as an argument to the thread target function and set it when you want to stop processing on all threads. When the event will be set, while loops will stop and the thread will gracefully terminate.

I also suggest you to wait for the thread to terminate by calling [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) method on your `Thread` object. If you need the results from your processing, this ensures that the results are available and the thread terminated. If you're using multiple threads, call `join` on all of them.

```
from threading import Thread, Event

def do_work_1(args):
    # Do your work here

def do_work_2(args):
    # Do your work here

def thread_target(stop_event, funcs, funcs_args):
    # Perform work until the event is set
    for idx, func in enumerate(funcs):
        func(funcs_args[idx])
        if stop_event.is_set():
           break

stop_event = Event()

sequential_work_funcs = [do_work_1, do_work_2, do_work_2]
# Add arguments you want to pass to functions 
# (args on the index get passed to func of same index)
sequential_work_funcs_args = [{}, {}, {}] 

# Pass the event as an argument to the target function
my_thread = Thread(target=thread_target, args=(stop_event, sequential_work_funcs, sequential_work_funcs_args))
my_thread.start()

# When you want to stop the threads
stop_event.set()

# Wait for thread to gracefully terminate if you need results of work
# join() is a blocking call that returns when the thread terminates
my_thread.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in the question I'm asking about calling different function sequentially, and not the same one over and over again so I'm not sure this helps

Comment: @chikchakchok I made an edit and I think it should answer your question now.

Comment: Oh I see, you want to stop your work functions and not wait for them to stop processing and then stop?

Comment: If that is the case, I suggest you make your work functions more granular and add checks in between. There is no nicer way to stop the threads gracefully. Some code has to execute and then a check can be done, this can't be avoided. The only other option is forceful termination of threads, which can't be done through the official Python libraries. You can use the OS level commands such as p_thread for forceful termination.